# Overflow with a flex div not working in FF

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple demo of an error I found. There is a flex div and a few images inside.

The sizes of the div and the images are unknown, I put some fixed values just to represent the problem.

The problem is that the images are not overflowing the div's width in FF, but they do in Chrome (the expected and desired behavior).

The main goal is to make only 3 images to be visible (33.3333% of the div's width for each image), even if there are more than 3 images.

Demo: http://codepen.io/alexandernst/pen/mPoeLP

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="box" src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img class="box" src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img class="box" src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img class="box" src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img class="box" src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid green;
  max-width: 33.33333%;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 10px;
  align-self: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest wrapping each of the images in a div and use the `.box` class on that instead.

Seems to work in Chrome 51 + FF 46

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.box img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you insert `box-sizing` on the root element?

Comment: Force of habit mostly and to make sure that all the widths etc include the borders/padding etc.

Comment: But in some cases you need to add a padding to the currently width so I think it is not so good in all environments (I think).

Comment: No but in general it's considered much simpler. Most modern CSS resets use it.

Comment: Nice to know it :). And the last question: is there an improvement on wrapping each image in a div for `box-sizing` property or is the same as put it directly on the images?

Comment: I think so...flexbox and unwrapped image can be a little funky.

Comment: It seems good (I put it directly on the images on my answer) but maybe in big projects it will crash something more. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have `padding-right`. Try adding [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)`: border-box;`:

```
.box {
  border: 1px solid green;
  max-width: 33.33333%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 10px;
  align-self: center;
}
```

`box-sizing` will take `padding` in its calculations.

[Updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONqMMO).

Comment: As I can understand, you want to avoid the overflow.